# mi imagen y texto no se ajustan con flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

estoy intentando hacer una media query y estoy usando flexbox para que la imagen y el texto cambien de tamaño cuando se ajusten a cierto parametro pero no se como hacerlo

la seccion consta de una un titulo y una descripcion y al lado derecho una imagen con animacion para que se mueva arriba y abajo

```
.home{
    display: flex; 
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: url(../images/home-bg-img.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.home .image img{
    width:40vw;
    animation: float 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes float{
    0%, 100%{
        transform: translateY(0rem);
    }
    50%{
        transform: translateY(-3.5rem);
    }
}

.home .content h3{
    font-size: 5.5rem;
    color: #333;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.home .content p{
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    color: #666;
    padding:1rem 0;
}
```

la media query consiste solo en posicionar la imagen en la parte superior y el texto abajo.

ademas cuando este por debajo de los 803px la imagen deberia reducirse junto con el texto

```
@media(max-width:803px){
.home{
        flex-flow: column-reverse;
    }

    .home .image img{
        width:100%;
    }

    .home .content h3{
        font-size: 3.6rem;
    }

    .home .content p{
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
   }
```

El `flex-flow: column-reverse;` si me funciona pero el texto y la imagen no cambia su tamaño

aqui les dejo el html

```
<section class="home" id="home">
        <div class="content">
            <h3> la mejor aplicacion movil</h3> 
            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt laudantium sit pariatur alias. Doloribus atque facilis architecto ex harum porro iste magnam ad, doloremque, obcaecati omnis nisi</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Descargalo Ahora</a>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="./images/home-img.png" alt="">
        </div>

    </section>
```

Comment: ¿Te aseguraste que estás entrando bien a las clases de tu html?

Comment: si amigo, el html es bastante corto. ya lo agregue

Comment: probaste quitando los ultimos 3 .home del css?

Comment: si y no funcionó